# UNIX - Sub of two concecutive fields with adding 1

Tags: unix

Would you kindly help me to resolve the following?

```
20066898701..20066901700
20066891201..20066893700
20066879201..20066888700
20009429701..20009439700
20009412201..20009414700
```

I have an input as above

1. I need to convert the .. to , seperated
2. Then the column 2 will be subtracted from column 1 and output to be added with 1

`20066898701..20066901700 => (20066901700-20066898701)+1 => 3000`

Comment: You say "column 2 will be subtracted from column 1" but your example shows column 1 subtracted from column 2.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe your output into the following Perl:
perl -ne 'my @fields = split /\s/, $_; foreach my $input (@fields) { if (/^(\d+)..(\d+)$/) { print $2 - $1 + 1, "\n"; } }'

What this does is firstly split the input on spaces (so your first line should work). It then runs a regular expression on each entry to match a string which only contains two numbers separated by .. - the brackets put the numbers in $1 and $2.

For example:
`echo "20066898701..20066901700" | perl -ne 'my @fields = split /\s/, $_; foreach my $input (@fields) { if (/^(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$/) { print $2 - $1 + 1, "\n"; } }'
3000`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/\.\./,/g'<erk|awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","}; { total = ($2 - $1) +1; print total}
```

Given a file named "erk", containing your data:

```
tom@holborn:~$  cat erk | sed 's/\.\./,/g'| awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","}; { total = ($2 - $1) +1; print total}'
3000
2500
9500
10000
2500
```

You could pipe the output of your application straight into sed, instead of cat

Comment: sed is unnecessary.

Comment: sed is nice, though.

Comment: Indeed, I meant sed is unnecessary in your code, but I like very much sed nevertheless.

Comment: I tend to write scripts in left-to-right order, so sed is the most straightforward way to do the first bit, then I think.. Ooh. Awk can do the next bit.. etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 20066898701..20066901700 20066891201..20066893700 20066879201..20066888700 20009429701..20009439700 20009412201..20009414700
do
    echo $i | awk -F "[.]+" '{ printf("%s\n",$2-$1+1); }'
done
3000
2500
9500
10000
2500
```

If the values are in a single line as it seems now, you can use the simpler:

```
awk -F "[.]+" '{ printf("%s\n",$2-$1+1); }' filename
```

Comment: Perhaps your `for` loop is just for demonstration, but if not it's a very inefficient way to do that.

Comment: The initial question was showing all values in a single line. It has been edited to show them in multiple lines after my reply. I'm providing a simpler solution now. Of course, launching an awk command for every data pair is highly inefficient but might be "unnoticeably" inefficient if the number of values is not significantly large.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash:

```
while IFS=. read -r field1 null field2
do
    echo $((field2 - field1 + 1))
done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
cat file-with-numbers.txt | while read i
do
  first=`echo $i | cut -f1 -d.`
  second=`echo $i | cut -f3 -d.`
  expr $second - $first + 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$/sprintf "%d,%d,%d",$1,$2,($2-$1)+1/eg;' filename
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\.\.(\d+)$/($2-$1)+1/eg;' filename
```

if you only want the difference